# Celery Chains: Do chains work is there is a one to many relationship with the functions?

Tags: python, celery

Chain documentation:  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Example from another thread: [Does a celery chain execute tasks in a specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553620/does-a-celery-chain-execute-tasks-in-a-specific-order)

```
@shared_task
def task_a():
    pass

@shared_task
def task_b():
    pass

@shared_task
def task_b():
    pass

@shared_task
def task_main():
    chain = task_a.s() | task_b.s() | task_c.s()
    chain()
```

Would this chain structure still work if I have a one to many relationship in Task A?

I.E.

- Task A is a function that searches for files
- Task B is a function that needs to be run on each file
- Task C is a function that is only run if Task B returns a positive result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tasks in chain are executed in order. To be more precise, we use *signatures* (low-level primitive) in Celery chains. More about it in the [Celery Workflows](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) document. If any part (signature) of your Chain should execute multiple tasks, then you use [Group](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups)

When you make a chain out of Group, and a signature you get what Celery refers to as [Chord](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords).

Let's say you have the following tasks: foo(), comp(), and final()
You can then form a Workflow similar to the following:

```
    -- comp ---
   /            \
foo -- comp -- final
   \            /
    -- comp ---

SA     G1       SB
```

Here SA is the first [signature](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures), G1 is a group of *three* instances of the "comp" task, and finally once they all finish working, final() task is executed (signature SB). There are few ways to create signatures, please read the "Celery Workflows" document thoroughly to understand those basic concepts. I called them tasks here... In reality they are all signatures (foo.s(), comp.s(), final.s(), or if you use immutable ones foo.si(), comp.si() and final.si()). Learn about the differences between mutable and immutable signatures too.